# python package error when running from sublime

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext2, anaconda

I installed the python package `isochrones` using `pip install isochrones`.

When I type `from isochrones.dartmouth import Dartmouth_Isochrone` in the `Sublime text editor` I get the following error:

```
from isochrones.dartmouth import Dartmouth_Isochrone
ImportError: No module named dartmouth
```

However, the same command works when I run it from `ipython`.

What's going on?! I have a long code, so working in `ipython` is not possible. I want to use `sublime`.

Comment: do you have more than 1 version of python on your system?

Comment: `which python` gives `/Applications/anaconda/bin/python`

Comment: can you try `/Applications/anaconda/bin/pip install isochrones`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) for Anaconda. Select **`Tools → Build System → New Build System...`** and replace the contents of the file that opens with the following:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["/Applications/anaconda/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

When you hit save, it should automatically open your User directory (`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User`). Save the file there as `Anaconda Python.sublime-build`. Finally, select **`Tools → Build System → Anaconda Python`** so the proper system will run when you select Build.

Now that the build system is all set up, you need to ensure that you're installing things under the right Python distribution. OS X comes with Python built-in as `/usr/bin/python`, with system packages residing in a range of possible directories, depending on which build of OS X you're using. From the command line, run

```
which pip
```

to ensure it points to the Anaconda installation. If it doesn't, you'll have to alter your `PATH` variable to put `/Applications/anaconda/bin` at the front, before `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. How to do that is beyond the scope of this answer, but it's easy to find out by a quick Google search.

You should now be able to use your Anaconda `pip`-installed packages with Sublime Text.

Comment: `which pip` gives `/Applications/anaconda/bin/pip`. I did what you just told me but still, I got the same error.